# Flutter : Is using Native Splash Screen better?

Tags: flutter, screen, native, splash-screen

I am using flutter_native_splash package. Which works fine. But what is the difference between using the native splash and a flutter page? Is there any difference regarding performance?

Answer (score 0):

when the flutter app is opened for the first time, there will be white screen for few seconds before any page is displayed.

to tackle that issue, `flutter_native_splash` can be used. It builds a native splash screen and will be displayed for few seconds until the first UI is drawn in the flutter app.

the native splash screen can also be closed programatically if needed it until some async task is done.

Answer (score 0):

The [flutter_native_splash](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_native_splash) displays the splash screen ***before*** the Flutter engine is finished loading.  If you use a Flutter page for a splash screen, it will be loaded ***after*** the Flutter engine is finished loading and there will be a delay during which a blank white screen will be displayed.

(Full disclosure - I maintain the flutter_native_splash package)